No appropriate font found for family name Arial. Implement IFontResolver and assign to GlobalFontSettings.FontResolver to use fonts
This is the error:

No appropriate font found for family name Arial. Implement IFontResolver and assign to GlobalFontSettings.FontResolver to use fonts

 using (SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog() )
 {
     if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
     {
        
         PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument();

         doc.Info.Title = "PDF";

       
         PdfPage page = doc.AddPage();

         XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);

     
         XFont font = new XFont("Arial", 25);

         for (int i = 0; i < txtBoxList.Count; i++)
         {
       
             gfx.DrawString(txtBoxList[i].Text, font, XBrushes.Black, new XPoint(0, 0));

         }
         doc.Save(sfd.FileName);
     }

In some textbox I write some text and I want to save in a PDF, but it gives me this error and I dont know what to do.

You are using the Core build of PDFsharp and this build works under Windows, Linux, MacOS and others. It can only use the fonts you provide using the IFontResolver interface.
If you want to run under Windows only, use the WPF or GDI+ build - they will use the fonts from the Windows folder automatically.
Otherwise implement IFontResolver.
Information about the available builds:
https://docs.pdfsharp.net/General/Overview/NuGet-Packages.html
Information about FontResolvers on the official project website:
https://docs.pdfsharp.net/PDFsharp/Topics/Fonts/About.html
